# Pass primitive data type into function parameter

Tags: php, types, parameters

Is there any way I can **pass a primitive data type into a function parameter** (or equivalently, store it into a variable) in PHP? By primitive types I mean `int`, `bool`, `double`, `string`, etc.

More specifically, I would like to do something like this:

```
function SomeFunc($DataType, $SomeOtherPara)
{
}

SomeFunc(int, "test1");
SomeFunc(bool, "test2");
```

A *possible* usage might be:

```
//! Cast the input parameter into a data type, recursively.
/*!
    \param[in]  $DataType            Data type, e.g. int, double, bool, string.
    \param[in]  $InputPara           Any input parameter.
*/
function TypeJuggleRecursive($DataType, $InputPara)
{
    if(is_array($InputPara))
    {
        // Work on each array element recursively.
        $ReturnPara = array();
        foreach($InputPara as $Key => $Value)
        {
            $ReturnPara[$Key] = TypeJuggleRecursive($DataType, $Value);
        }
        return $ReturnPara;
    }
    else
    {
        // Cast to data type.
        return ($DataType)$InputPara;
    }
}

TypeJuggleRecursive(bool, $_GET);
TypeJuggleRecursive(int, $_POST);
```

An obvious workaround would be to use strings instead, i.e. `"string"` for `string`, `"int"` for `int`, etc., but that seems dumb.

Comment: Not that I know of. Interesting problem though. I would just pass string or int (some identifier to switch on) type even if it seems "dumb" it's not like there are millions of data types commonly used in php.

Comment: I don't think you can just use int, string, etc. I would assume those are reserved keywords, but don't quote me on that. even the gettype() function (which I would use for something like this), returns the types in string format: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php

Comment: gettype would only be useful if he wanted to cast the passed var as its own type. In this case, he wants to pass the type to cast AS, different than whatever $SomeOtherPara would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it was a dumb way to do it, I don't think settype() would use a string :)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php

Comment: Makes sense, I'll be happy if PHP is just as dumb as me. :-P

Answer (score 1):

There are only 9 primitive data types. You can use `gettype`:

```
function my_cast($value, $new_type) {
    switch(gettype($value)) {
        case 'boolean':
        case 'integer':
        case 'double':
        case 'string':
            // do something
            break;
        case 'array':
        case 'object':
        case 'resource':
            // do something else
            break;
        case 'NULL':
        default:
            // 'unknown type'
    }
}
```

You won't be able to actually pass around types in PHP.